# Как сделать QAction и QMenu внутри QMenuBar максимальной высоты?

Tags: c++, qt

Не получается никак сделать содержимое `QMenuBar` во всю её высоту:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Высота `QMenuBar` вычисляется от высоты экрана. Замером установил, что она равна 29 пикселям. При этом, если я ставлю 29px через `setStyleSheet()`, то все `QAction` и `QMenu` просто исчезают, а вот при 24px они занимают ровно весь `QMenuBar`. Но это никуда не годится, такие цифры индивидуальны для каждой машины. Нужно каким-то образом растягивать на всю высоту. Перепробовал уже всё, что смог, но никак не выходит. Буду благодерн за помощь.

```
menubar->setStyleSheet("QMenuBar:maximized { min-height: 15px; max-height: 25px; }"
                        //"QMenuBar { height: 20px; }"
                        //"QMenuBar::item { height: 25px; }"
                        //"QAction { height: 25px; }"
);
```

Comment: Я уже начинаю думать, что проще оставить `QToolBar`, кинуть туда `QPushButton` и установить в неё меню через `setMenu()`... Таблица стилей чрезвычайно кривая и не доведённая до ума вещь.

Comment: попробуйте `QMenuBar::item { ...; padding: 20px 20px;}`

Comment: @S.Nick, нет. А как это должно было помочь? Я просто не понимаю логики разработчиков. Элементарнейшая потребность, и нет никаких средств, чтобы её реализовать. Опять же, при переполненнии -- просто выносит за границы.

Comment: вы можете как-то нарисовать что вы хотите получить?

Comment: @S.Nick, да просто чтобы выделенная область была на всю высоту `QMenuBar`. На скрине же вижно, что это не так. Если написать `"QMenuBar { height: 24px; }"`, то всё как нужно, но проблема в том, что фактическая высота 29px, а какая будет дельта на других машинах, я понятия не имею. Если хотя бы на пиксель переполнить, то `QMenuBar` будет просто пуст.

Comment: а если написать `QMenuBar { font-size: 24px; }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем, лучший вариант, который я нашёл, — это использовать `QToolBar` вместе с `QToolButton`, а где нужно меню — использовать метод `QToolButton::setMenu()`. Смотрится неплохо и, что самое главное, `QToolButton` - наследник `QWidget`, в отличии от `QAction`.